# "Inward" facing bar labels in a bar chart with negative values with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I set inward facing bar labels in a bar chart with positive and negative values in ggplot2? I.e. the bar labels should be facing the 0 axis.

```
df <- data.frame(trt = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
                 outcome = c(2.3, 1.9, 0.5, -0.5))

ggplot(df, aes(trt, outcome, label = outcome)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
           position = "identity") + 
  geom_text(vjust = "inward", color = 'red')
```

`vjust = "inward"` is [obviously](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1799) not the way to go, since "Inward and outward are relative to the physical middle of the plot, not where the 0 axes are".

Update:

[image: geom_bar inward]

Comment: Is `geom_text(vjust=c(1, 1, 1, 0), nudge_y=c(-0.1, -0.1, -0.1, 0.4), color = 'red') ` something like you're after?

Comment: @hrbrmstr: In principle yes, the looks are fine (well, I'd rather use (-)0.05 for all `nudge_y` values, but that's just optics). My main concern is, however, that I want to make many graphs like this and I would have to adjust each graph by hand depending on the values of the variables. So overall, not quite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to set the `vjust` inside of the `aes` mappings to control differently for each row, here based on whether it is positive or negative:

```
ggplot(df, aes(trt, outcome, label = outcome)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
           position = "identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(vjust = outcome > 0)
            , color = 'red')
```

[image]

If you want to move the labels around more precisely (instead of just `vjust = 0` or `vjust = 1` that you can get from a logical), you can use `ifelse` and define you positions more exactly:

```
ggplot(df, aes(trt, outcome, label = outcome)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
           position = "identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(vjust = ifelse(outcome > 0
                               , 1.5, -0.5) )
            , color = 'red'
            )
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Both putting the `vjust =` into the `aes()` (did not know that this was possible and that it allowed the rhs to be evaluated) and the `outcome > 0` as well. I am just thinking about a way to push the labels somewhat further inward. (I don't know how to say this better, but on my machine all labels seem to be pushed on row of pixels to the bottom, so the last row of pixels at the bottom of the - 0.5 are not on the bar, but on the white line. See the graph I added to the post.)

Comment: See edit for an example of finer control. Play with the choices in `ifelse` if you want to push it a little further in either direction.