# ggplot2: How to conditionally change geom_text's vjust when low bars make text exceed bar's bottom

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text, ggproto

When plotting a bar chart, I often add labels to bars to signify the y-value for each bar. However, I run into trouble when the bar becomes too low, making the label unreadable or simply ugly.

### Example

```r
library(ggplot2)

df_blood <- data.frame(blood_type = c("O-", "O+",   "A-",   "A+",   "B-",   "B+",   "AB-",  "AB+"),
                       frequency  = c(0.13, 0.35, 0.08, 0.3, 0.02, 0.08, 0.01, 0.02))

ggplot(df_blood, aes(x = blood_type, y = frequency, fill = blood_type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = frequency), color = "blue", vjust = 1, size = 7)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Looking at the bar of `AB-` we can see that the `0.01` text is exceeding the bar height (at the bar's bottom). In such cases, I'd like to change the `vjust` of `geom_text()` to `0`.

---

### Another Example with different y scale

Here I'm using the same `size = 7` as above for `geom_text()`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df_something <- data.frame(something = c("a", "b", "c"),
                   quantity = c(10000, 7800, 500))

ggplot(df_something, aes(x = something, y = quantity)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = quantity), color = "red", vjust = 1, size = 7)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Here we see that the bar for `c` has the `500` text exceeding the bottom of the bar. So in such case, I'd also like to change `geom_text()`'s `vjust` to `0`, for bar `c` only.

---

### To sum up

Although there are solutions to change `vjust` conditionally with a simple `ifelse` (see [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54098479/6105259)) based on the y-value, I'm trying to figure out how to condition `vjust` such that it would work regardless of the values on the y scale. Rather, the rule should be that if the bar's height is lower than size of `geom_text()`, the text position will move to be on top. Thanks!

---

**EDIT**

---

Based on the discussion below with @Paul, I wonder whether it could be easier to condition `vjust` on whether `geom_text()` position overlies `y = 0`, and if it does, change `vjust` to `0`.

---

**EDIT 2**

---

[This SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36327897/6105259) (credit to [@Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65883795/ggplot2-how-to-conditionally-change-geom-texts-vjust-when-low-bars-make-text-e#comment116579054_65921299) for finding) seems close enough to what I'm asking. It dynamically changes the `size` of `geom_text()` to fit bar width, and is working even when resizing the plot. So I think this provides basis to what I'm after, just instead of tweaking `size` I need to tweak `vjust`, and instead of conditioning it on bar width I need to condition it on bar height. Unfortunately it is too complex for my understanding of `ggproto` and alike, so I don't know how to adapt it to my case.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to convert the `size` value into `y` axis value? Then it might be possible to achieve your goal with `vjust = ifelse()` inside `aes()`

Comment: @Paul, I don't know how to make such conversion. I agree it's key to solving the problem, unless there are other methods that circumvent that need.

Comment: From [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html#font-size) we can read that "the `size` of text is measured in mm." Then, the text will remain of the same size even if you change the "final" size of your plot. Then I think we need to know the final size of your plot to find a solution. Is it an explicit style requirement or you can set it as you like?

Comment: @Paul, I commented at your solution below. Maybe we need/could condition `vjust` not on the `size` of `geom_text()` but on whether `geom_text()` overlies `y = 0`? I think this will achieve the same desired output., just by a different (and perhaps more attainable) condition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As an out-of-the-box option to achieve your desired result I would suggest to have a look at the `ggfittext` package which has some options to put the labels outside of the bars if they don't fit inside or to shrink the labels. Additionally there are also options to add some padding around the labels. However, it uses a no-default sizing policy so you you have to multiply default units by `ggplot2::.pt`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfittext)

df_something <- data.frame(something = c("a", "b", "c"),
                           quantity = c(10000, 7800, 500))

ggplot(df_something, aes(x = something, y = quantity)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "black") +
  geom_bar_text(aes(label = quantity), 
                color = "red", 
                vjust = 1, 
                size = 7 * ggplot2::.pt, 
                min.size = 7 * ggplot2::.pt,
                padding.x = grid::unit(0, "pt"),
                padding.y = grid::unit(0, "pt"),
                outside = TRUE)
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: label
```

[image]

```r
df_blood <- data.frame(blood_type = c("O-", "O+",   "A-",   "A+",   "B-",   "B+",   "AB-",  "AB+"),
                       frequency  = c(0.13, 0.35, 0.08, 0.3, 0.02, 0.08, 0.01, 0.02))

ggplot(df_blood, aes(x = blood_type, y = frequency, fill = blood_type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar_text(aes(label = frequency), 
                color = "blue", 
                vjust = 1, 
                size = 7 * ggplot2::.pt, 
                min.size = 7 * ggplot2::.pt,
                padding.x = grid::unit(0, "pt"),
                padding.y = grid::unit(0, "pt"),
                outside = TRUE)
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: label
```

[image]

Comment: First, this is outstanding. Second, would you mind elaborating more on "it uses a no-default sizing policy so you have to multiply default units by `ggplot2::.pt`" ? I don't understand the mechanism underlying the multiplication by `ggplot2::.pt`.

Comment: Hi Emman. By default I mean that in ggplot2 all sizes are measured in "mm", including fontsize. See [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html#font-size-1). For convenience ggplot2 provides the constant `.pt` to convert from "mm" to the more usual "pt" or "points", i.e. if you want a font size of "7pt" you can do `size = 7 / .pt`. Having said this, by non-default I mean that `ggfittext` uses "pt" as the unit for fontsite, i.e. `size = 7` will give you a font of size 7pt. Hence if you want the "default" ggplot2 sizes you have to multiply by ".pt". A bit confusing, but ..

Answer (score 2):

vjust can take a vector of inputs equal to the size of the x - axis as well.
The order of the vjust(where I put the 0) is based on the order of the dataset not the display shown in ggplot. You can factor blood_type to be very specific about where you would like each bar to be and control the vjust a little better.

```
library(ggplot2)

df_blood <- data.frame(blood_type = c("O-", "O+",   "A-",   "A+",   "B-",   "B+",   "AB-",  "AB+"),
                       frequency  = c(0.13, 0.35, 0.08, 0.3, 0.02, 0.08, 0.01, 0.02))

ggplot(df_blood, aes(x = blood_type, y = frequency, fill = blood_type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = frequency), color = "blue", vjust = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1), size = 7)
```

Comment: This is an interesting feature I was unaware of. It might come handy in the future, but right now I don't know how to utilize this to condition `vjust` on whether `geom_text()`'s `size` makes the text exceed the bottom part of the bar.

Comment: ok I understand, yea this feature would require you to know if the bar would be too small to fit the text. I am not sure how to determine the size of the bar and text to see if the text is too large for that bar

Answer (score 1):

Just found this while [googling around](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1799):
Try to use `vjust = "inward"`. However this might lead to other problems (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39795449/inward-facing-bar-labels-in-a-bar-chart-with-negative-values-with-ggplot2))...

```
ggplot(df_something, aes(x = something, y = quantity)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = quantity), color = "red", vjust = "inward", size = 7)
```

[image]

[OLD post]

I post this as an "answer" just to show what I mean. It will be improved with feedback.

As stated [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html#font-size), "the size of text is measured in mm". Then it will always have the same size whatever the final size of your plot is.

I thing we need to know if you have to keep a final dimension for your plot.
Ex:

```
ggsave(filename = "test_small.png", height = 5, units = "cm")
```

[image: Small plot]

```
ggsave(filename = "test_big.png", height = 20, units = "cm")
```

[image: Big plot]

Comment: Thanks. I think that if there's no other solution, we could set specific dimensions for the entire plot and work with that. However, it would make the solution unscalable. Right? Unless we could write a function that would optimize `geom_text`'s `size` too for any given plot dimensions.

Comment: @Emman I agree, this was just to illustrate my comment. Just found `vjust="inward"`, maybe it will do the trick.

Comment: Very cool, but I cannot follow the rule. See [here](https://i.imgur.com/tIRzFRw.png) for running the following code: `df_blood <- data.frame(blood_type = c("O-", "O+",   "A-",   "A+",   "B-",   "B+",   "AB-",  "AB+"),
                       frequency  = c(0.13, 0.35, 0.08, 0.3, 0.02, 0.08, 0.01, 0.02))

ggplot(df_blood, aes(x = blood_type, y = frequency, fill = blood_type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = frequency), color = "blue", vjust = "inward", size = 7)`

Comment: yes, I was checking this and got overexcited ^^ it seems they are limitations to this, I try to find more infos about that.

Comment: @Emman Well after some research, I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36319229/ggplot2-geom-text-resize-with-the-plot-and-force-fit-text-within-geom-bar). Maybe it will be necessary to create your own geom as suggested by the validated answer. But this is far beyond my knowledge of ggplot2...

Comment: Thanks @Paul, I appreciate your effort. I remember seeing that SO post but I forgot about it. Unfortunately nor am I proficient enough in `ggplot2` programming to adapt it to my case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the labels within the columns, could you just put them on top and it would get around your problem? It works for all columns and you wouldn't need to worry about selecting individuals ones. Its probably cleaner to have all labels above rather than have some within and others above.

```
library(ggplot2)
df_something <- data.frame(something = c("a", "b", "c"),
                           quantity = c(10000, 7800, 500))
ggplot(data = df_something, aes(x = something, y = quantity)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge", fill = "black") +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = quantity, y = quantity + 50),
    position = position_dodge(0.9),
    vjust = 0,
    color = "red",
    size = 7
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Placing the label within the bars is a choice guided by an explicit style requirement.